# Can not install Ganache GUI on Ubuntu?

Tags: ganache, installation

I am trying to install Ganache GUI on my ubuntu 18.04. I downloaded the Ganache-2.0.1.AppImage from the site. On the site it says that the package installs automatically when double clicked. But it is giving error of not finding any application to open the file.

I have installed the Ganache cli by this command 
"npm install -g ganache-cli"

Is it not possible to install the GUI for Ganache on linux? If yes please tell me how?

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to mark the AppImage file as executable program before you can run it.

1. Right click on the file and go to `Properties` option;
2. Under the "Permissions" tab, check the "Allow executing file as a program" checkbox;
3. Double click to run;
4. Optionally accept the offer to integrate and create a shortcut.

Answer (score 3):

Open terminal and type below commands,

```
$ git clone https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache.git
$ cd ganache
$ npm install
$ npm start
```

This get instruction in detail, you can get it from: [https://eattheblocks.com/installing-the-the-ganache-gui-episode-13](https://eattheblocks.com/installing-the-the-ganache-gui-episode-13/)/

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to install Ganache on the Ubuntu is to download the Ganache from the below given Link

Link : https://www.trufflesuite.com/ganache

then change your directory to the file where you have downloaded

EG: cd/Downloads

then copy the file name of the downloaded file and then make the file executable using chmod terminal command by typing the below command

terminal :

`chmod 777 Ganache-2.1.0.AppImage`

and then this other command

`./Ganache-2.1.0.AppImage`

wait for few minutes until the popup comes and then click ok and the Gananche is installed.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried bellow commands in my Windows 8.1

- $ npm install --global --production windows-build-tools

  $ git clone https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache.git

  $ cd ganache

  $ npm install

Answer (score 0):

Manually add an appimage software shortcut to application menu in Ubuntu

1. Download ganache image from [here](https://trufflesuite.com/ganache/)
2. chmod 777 ganache-2.5.4-linux-x86_64.AppImage
3. Download any image to use it as icon for app
4. Open the terminal
5. Navigate to the /usr/share/applications directory.
6. Create a new file with a .desktop extension in the applications directory.
7. Open the file with nano **sudo user**
8. Save your file and exit the terminal.

### ganache.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=ganache
Exec=/opt/ganache-2.5.4-linux-x86_64.AppImage
Comment=ganache-2.5.4-linux-x86_64
Icon=/opt/ganache-logo-dark.svg
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Encoding=UTF-8
Categories=Utility;
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the ganache-ui is that unbuntu dosen't know what to do with the AppImage file. You must install Fuse library.

run this in your terminal
[sudo apt install libfuse2]